# Determinant of the sum of an identity matrix and a rank-two-symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, block-matrices

Suppose $I$ is an $n \times n$ identity matrix, and $S$ is the $n \times n$ symmetric matrix with rank equals two.  I was reading something saying that:
$$\det(I-S)=(1-\lambda_1)(1-\lambda_2)$$

where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the two largest (in absolute values) eigenvalues of $S$.  Can anyone provide some clues for proving this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Notice that $S$ is symmetric real then it's diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$ and since it's rank is $2$ then it's similar to
$$\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,0,\ldots,0)$$
where $\lambda_i\ne0$ so $I-S$ is similar to
$$\operatorname{diag}(1-\lambda_1,1-\lambda_2,1,\ldots,1)$$
and then the result follows easily.

Comment: Thank you!  That looks great.  Just add the following comment that may be helpful for beginners: $D=P^{-1}SP$.  Consider $P^{-1}(I-S)P=P^{-1}P-P^{-1}SP=I-D$.  So $I-S$ is similar to $I-D$, and therefore they have the same determinant.

Comment: This is a useful comment! You're welcome:-)

Comment: I can't believe I'm just learning this.

Answer (score 1):

Diagonalizing does not matter much; if you know the full list of eigenvalues and multiplicities, adding, say, $tI$ just adds $t$ to each eigenvalue. The same would work for something with nontrivial Jordan form, you don't need to know full details of the Jordan form, just the diagonal entries.